# trabalhando com datas

Tags: mysql

Poderiam ajudar-me por favor,
tenho uma coluna data de atendimento que com base nela me traga o ultimo dia daquele mês e eu calcule aquela data_final_mês + prazo pagamento e a partir daí eu consiga saber qual é a data final que o cliente tem para o pagamento .

```
select DATE_ADD(last_day(now()), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

tentei este script mas ele me retorna em função da data actual, mas eu quero em função da minha coluna `dataAtendimento`.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Você poderia construir a sua query como nesse exemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(last_day(dataAtendimento), INTERVAL 10 DAY) as dataPagamento 
FROM `nome_da_sua_tabela`
```

Ps: altere a tabela do código acima para o nome da sua tabela.

Comment: obrigada Alexandre